# Trying to initiate draggable for imgviewer2 after zoom level equals 1

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am using  jQuery imgviewer2 plugin which is designed to zoom and pan images. I am trying to initiate the draggable after the image is zoomed and the zoom level is 1. Right now, it is either disable draggable or enable it.

Please forgive me I am not jQuery expert I just need an idea if it is possible to initiate imgviewer2 after the image is zoomed and zoom level is 1.

This is the zoom [imgviewer2](https://github.com/waynegm/imgViewer2) I am using.

This is the code I wrote, but I am sure this is not the right way to achieve what I am trying to do.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var $imagezoom = $(".image1").imgViewer2({
    zoomMax: 2,
    "dragable": false,
    onReady: function() {
      var zoomlevel = this.getZoom();
      if (zoomlevel == 2) {
        "dragable": true
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Thank you so much for all the help. I would really appreciate .

Comment: I can only find one working jsfiddle that uses this plugin.  The code doesn't look anything like yours.  I would try starting with this code and see if it solves your problem.  Just replace the image in this example with your image.  https://jsfiddle.net/sw5bdy6f/

Comment: In what scenario the zoom level is 2 when you initiate the plugin? Isn't 1 by default?

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your response, what I am trying to achieve is not to have draggable enable until the zoom level is greater than 1. I have been reading about this plugin alot couldn;t think of any way. 

the problem is when the dragable is enabled the scroll doesn't work on mobile because the image is full screen. so I am trying to disable it until the zoom is greater than 1.

Comment: I am trying to achieve the scenario where I can check if the zoom is greater than 1 and then enable draggable functionality. I am trying to get draggable disabled at first and trigger when zooming only. and I know I am doing pretty bad job at it. any idea regarding this will be so helpful.